# numbers option in acmart natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, latexmk, acm

I'm having a bad time compiling a paper with acm style.

The command I use to compile is:

```
latexmk -bibtex -xelatex -pvc -pdf -view=none index.tex
```

I use the acmart \documentclass like this:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,natbib=true,anonymous=true]{acmart}
```

Bibliography style set to:

```
\bibliographystyle{acm-plain}
```

And I'm adding the citation with the commands:

```
\cite \citep \citeauthors \citeyear (depending on what I need obviously)
```

The compiler is telling that the bibliography is not compatible with author-year citations. With

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

it does work. However, citations are no longer numeric but in the form [author et al. YEAR].

Lastly: setting natbib=false in the documentstyle and importing

```
 \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

does work (running latexmk twice), but with the error "Command \citename already defined"

How am I supposed to get a paper like the one from the following link? https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acm-conference-proceedings-new-master-template/pnrfvrrdbfwt

Thanks, Nicolò

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you use ACM, you probably want to say

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
```

`acm-plain` is an old style, not compatible with the new ACM

Second, if you want to have auhor-year scheme, just put in the preamble

```
\citestyle{acmauthoryear}
```

note `acm` here:  this sets author-year format according to ACM rules

Comment: Using \bibliograpystyle{ACM-Reference-Format} alone I got citations in the format [author year], and not numeric. Using: \setcitestyle{numbers} it works, thanks